# Boot Problem Windows

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a little problem with boot ubuntu DVD. My OS is windows 8.1 and my computer isn't laptop. The problem that is DVD isn't boot, and when I run boot help on DVD, it stop running and this is the error:

```
An error occurred:
Permission denied
for more information please see the log files: c:\users\...\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
```

Comment: Please describe how do you try to boot from DVD. It seems that you are not trying to boot  from it, but are trying to run wubi from Windows.

Comment: @Pilot6 When I insert my win8 installer (for example,) my system boot with it. But when I try that with Ubuntu DVD it doesn't work.

Comment: When you insert a disk from a running OD, it does not BOOT from it. It starts an autorun application. You need to google what booting is. And I do not recommend installing an OS with this level of knowledge.

Comment: Whatever tnx. @Pilot6

Comment: wasn't the support for wubi stopped after 13.10?

Comment: @RonnieDroid Tnx for ur help, but I could solve my problem. I dont know what is the major problem, but I boot 12.02LTS (that I think) then update version to 14LTS.

Comment: why don't you try to install it from USB? and search in Google for how to make a UEFI bootable  USB in windows without using an app. that may help u

Answer (score 0):

You can not run an install on win 8 through wubi. you have to do a lot of maneuvering to get it to work and unless you have the technical skill i would not recommend it. I don't believe running the live disk will work either even if it where a usb.

Answer (score 0):

We have all had to overcome the initial challenge of installing a second OS from Windows and entering the discovery phase of Linux for which Ubuntu is a good choice.

You could either utilize a VM from within Windows or dual-boot Ubuntu

1. for the VM approach start [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)
2. a brief overview for a dual-boot installation follows:

   1. backup data files from your Windows installation
   2. understand BIOS boot settings, [start here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm)
   3. download the latest Ubuntu .iso file
   4. create a BOOT DVD from Windows (use imgBurn)
   5. shutdown your machine
   6. install Ubuntu in dual boot mode, allowing Ubuntu to resize your partition